# If $f=u+iv$ is an entire function. Is that true that if $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}v(z)=0$ then $v$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, definition

> Let $f=u+iv$ be an entire function. Is that true that if
> $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}v(z)=0$ then $v$ is bounded?

My attempt was to look to the definition of this limit:

$$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists M>0 \text{ such that }|v(z)|<\varepsilon, \text{ always that }|z|>M.$$

But, is it possible to prove that $v$ is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You don't need complex analysis for this conclusion. A *continuous* function on $\Bbb C$ (or on $\Bbb R^n$) which has a limit at $\infty$ is bounded.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, do you have any source for me to see this result?

Comment: @Manatee It's not hard to prove. Convince yourself that the set $\{z:|v(z)| \geq \epsilon \}$ is compact for each $\epsilon$ and take it from there.

Comment: I wonder, maybe the question meant to ask whether $f$ is bounded rather than $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $v$ is bounded. This is a standard argument in real analysis. I'll cite the theorems used:

Since $|v|$ is continuous, it follows from the extreme value theorem for compact metric spaces that for any compact set $K$, $|v||_{K}$ attains a maximum (and minimum) on $K$. By the Heine Borel theorem, for every $R > 0$, the closed disk $\overline{D_R(0)}$ centered at $0$ of radius $R$ is compact. Hence $|v|$ is bounded on any such disk by some constant $M_R$. Now pick $R > 0$ such that $|v(z)| < 1$ when $|z| > R$. Then $|v| \leq \max(M_R, 1)$ on $\mathbb{C}$.